# Render a Complex Mongo Document to a Template in Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In a Metoer app, a mongodb collection contains documents that describe projects. They vary greatly as to personnel and titles and other facts.

When a user selects a project from a sidebar list I want to render all the information in the document to a reactive template.

The sidebar list might look like this:

- **Brooklyn Bridge**
- **Hoover Dam Eifel**
- **Tower**

The mongo document for Hoover Dam might look like this:

```
{
"_id": "dksld888-aaaa-12345",
"name" : "Hoover Dam",
"year_built" : 1931,
... other facts... 
"architects" : 
    [
        {
          "person_id" : "1a2d528c-6509-4c3a",
          "title" : "Lead Designer"
        },
        {
           "person_id" : "4a3d-81e0-5a3f-2343",
            "title" : "Assistant"
        }
    ]
... other job descriptions... 
}
```

The person_id field contains the ObjectID of the entry in another collection that has lots more detailed information on that person.

The system is intended to allow a user to drill down from Project Name to Project Details to Person Details (or activate editing of data in the Project details template).

I'm stumped how to proceed with rendering the Project details document to a reactive template (something recursive to loop and drill down through the doc). I'm also happy to change the structure of the projects collection if I've done it wrong.

Any ideas would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, make a template that renders the project. Then set up an event listener on your sidebar so that when the user clicks an item, a Session value is set containing the current project id. Have the project template listen to the Session value to draw the corresponding project.

Within the project template, create a list of people using {{#each person}} and then have the template draw the people within the project. You should probably write a convenience method that fetches the person by given person_id.

I would add code to my answer but there's a lot to do here, so if you can't figure it out, please specify what you're getting stuck on and I'll try to help.